# Как перезапустить nodejs сервис с помощью GitLab CI?

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Для загрузки REST API (express.js) на тестовый сервер использую GitLab CI.
Идея в том, чтобы после коммита, файлы с GIT Lab загружались на хостинг, выполнялась установка пакетов и запускался сервер.
Часть кода .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
 - init
 - dev

init:
 stage: init
 cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-${CI_COMMIT_SHA}-npm-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
   - node_modules/
 script:
  - rm ./package-lock.json
  - npm install
 artifacts:
  expire_in: 1 day
  paths:
   - node_modules/

dev_deploy:
 stage: dev
 script:
 - ls -la
 - ssh $SSH_USERNAME_DO@$SSH_HOST_DO "cd .../.../appfolder && NODE_ENV=development node server && exit"
only:
 - dev
```

Работает это плохо:

1. Каждый раз устанавливаются пакеты, что долго и не нужно вовсе для каждой загрузки, можно ли как-то делать это только в нужный момент?
2. Вообще не понятно, как остановить express.js перед его новым запуском, иными словами как перезапустить сервер?

Comment: `npm install` устанавливает только изменённые/новые пакеты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу расписать, как я делаю для dev сервака у нас.

1. Запускать сервис лучше под чем-то. Мы используем [suprvisord](http://supervisord.org/). Для него конфиг файл типо такого:

   ```
   [program:node_server]
   command=node server.js -logFile 1.log > /dev/null 2>& 1&
   directory=/путь/до/директории_с_проектом
   user=www
   environment=NODE_ENV="development"
   numprocs=1
   process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
   autostart=true
   autorestart=true
   startretries=3
   stopsignal=TERM
   stdout_logfile=/var/log/node-server.log
   redirect_stderr=true
   ```

   Рестарт сервисиов в suprvisord через `suprvisorctl restart имя_сервиса`.
2. В CI лучще копировать куда-нить проект из гита:

   ```
   stages:
   - deploy

   deploy:
     stage: deploy
     tags: [dev]
     script:
     # папка, куда копировать хотим, в раннере в гитлабе настраивается
     # $webroot - это тот самый /путь/до/директории_с_проектом
     - if [ -z "$webroot" ]; then echo "Need to set webroot" && exit 1; fi
     # копирум репо в папочку
     - rsync -rv ./ $webroot --exclude '.git' --exclude '.gitlab-ci.yml' --exclude '.gitignore'
     - cd $webroot
     # удаляем лок
     - test -e package-lock.json && rm package-lock.json && echo 'package-lock.json removed' || echo 'no package-lock.json'
     # ставим зависимости
     - npm install
     # ребутаем сервис в supervisor'е
     - sudo supervisorctl restart node_server:node_server_00
     - echo 'Git Gud'
     only:
     - dev
   ```